# Passing incorrect parameters to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a bookings model, controller, view. Users can make a booking and a driver can later claim a booking. The booking creation is working fine, I am able to display all the unclaimed bookings to a driver, however I am unable to update the booking with a Driver ID when the driver hits the claim button. I have added the driver_id to the booking model and trying to use the update method in bookings controller to update the driver's field, I think I am not passing the parameters correctly to the link_to. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong:

Booking Controller:

```
def update
    if @booking.update(booking_params)
      redirect_to @booking, notice: "Updated..."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def set_booking
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end

    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:location_pickup, :location_dropoff, :date_pickup, :date_dropoff, :weight, :load_type)
    end
end
```

Driver controller

class DriversController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_driver!, except: [:show]

```
def show
    @driver = Driver.find(params[:id])
end
def index
    @bookings = Booking.where(:driver_id => nil)
end
```

end

(drivers/index.html.erb) Driver View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Listings
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= current_driver.email %>
                <% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">

                        </div>      
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <td> <%= booking.location_pickup %>  </td>

                            <td><%= booking.location_dropoff %></td>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">

                            <%= link_to "Claim", update_bookings_path(@booking, driver_id: current_driver.id), :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                        </div>              

                    </div>
                <% end %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

 devise_for     :users, 
                        :path => '', 
                        :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
                        :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'
                                                        }
 devise_for :drivers, 
            :path => '/drivers', 
            :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},            
            :controllers => { :registrations => "drivers/registrations" }

 resources :users, only: [:show]
 resources :drivers, only: [:show, :index, :claim]
 resources :bookings
end
```

**Rake routes**

```
edit_booking GET    /bookings/:id/edit(.:format)     bookings#edit
           booking GET    /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#show
                   PATCH  /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#update
                   PUT    /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#update
                   DELETE /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#destroy
```

Comment: can you share your routes...The second parameter is not the way to pass...But I can give you correct path only after seeing the routes...

Comment: thanks SnehaT, I have added the routes. Please let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Claim", booking_path(booking.id, driver_id: current_driver.id), :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: tried that as well, I am getting an error undefined method `update_bookings_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8be0123e28>:0x007f8be011a0a8>

Comment: My route definitely shows the update method- added rake routes to the main description

Comment: <%= link_to "Claim", booking_path(booking.id, driver_id: current_driver.id), :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

Comment: Great.. Please accept the answer as i have chanded it.